# Capturing Visual Stadio Command Line Compilier (CL.EXE) Output With Regular Expressions

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I've been trying to set up VS command line compiler to use in VS code IDE. I have read the examples and can use GCC with no problem but need to use VS compiler now too.

I have tried a single line problem matcher and I multiple one. Yet VC code seems to capture nothing.

Here is an example of output with error from the compiler:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.40629 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
helloWorld.c
..\Code\helloWorld.c(7) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
```

Using the regExpr Expression:

```
(.*\n){2,3}\S+(\d+)\W+:\s(\bwarning|error\b\s\w+):\s(\w+\s\w+)\s+:\s(.*)$
```

It captures all the info I need (checked my work here: https://regex101.com/)

but when I put it in a Tasks.json file for VS code it doesn't work.

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "Build",
"args": [
    "${fileBasename}"
],
"isShellCommand": true,
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "Build",
        // Make this the default build command.
        "isBuildCommand": true,
        // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
        "showOutput": "always",
        // No args
        "args": [
            "all"
        ],
        // Use the standard less compilation problem matcher.
        "problemMatcher": {
            "owner": "cpp",
            "fileLocation": [
                "relative",
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "pattern": {
                "regexp": "(.*\n){2,3}\\S+(\\d+)\\W+:\\s(\bwarning|error\b\\s\\w+):\\s(\\w+\\s\\w+)\\s+:\\s(.*)$",
                "file": 1,
                "line": 2,
                "severity": 3,
                "code": 4,
                "message": 5
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Anyone know how to setup VS Code IDE to use VS command line compiler? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why are you doing this? Wouldn't you prefer to use the return value from cl.exe instead of its text output?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebh0y918.aspx

Comment: If you want to get the IDE to highlight error code you you define a problem matcher https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher

Answer (score 0):

The first two lines in your output can be avoided by adding `/nologo` flag to the compiler. So your **tasks.json** should be:

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "Build",
        "isBuildCommand": true,
        "showOutput": "always",
        "args": [
            "all"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": {
            "owner": "cpp",
            "severity": "info",    // treat note as info
            "fileLocation": "absolute",
            "pattern": {
                "regexp": "^(.*)\\((\\d+)\\):\\s+(warning|error|note)\\s*(\\w+)?:\\s+(.*)$",
                "file": 1,
                "location": 2,
                "severity": 3,
                "code": 4,
                "message": 5
            }
        }
    }
]
```